# MYSQLI_fetch_array $row["fn"];

Tags: php, mysqli, formatting, row

I am using the following code to display a thumbnail gallery.  This code was taken from another stackoverflow question

```
$count=0;
$arr=array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
 $img = $row["fn"];
  if (empty($img)) { break; }
  $thumb = 'images/th_'.$img;
  if ($count == 8) { break; }

  $i=$arr[$count%4];    

  $ths.='<div class="ui-block-'.$i.'"><img src="'.$thumb.'"></div>';

  $count++;
};
```

I don't understand $row["fn"]; and I can't find anything in google. Is "fn" part of the formatting characters (such as \n)?  Sorry for such a basic question but I really cannot find the answer elsewhere and I have been looking for two hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [array syntax.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

While `$row` here is filled with database row contents, and have its keys corresponding to database columns. If you selected a column named `fn` in your query, there will be element with key `fn` in `$row` array

Answer (score 0):

it will be generally the name of image or it will be a sequence number or some formated name of the image